# Jomsocial Custom Profile - Display email used on first page of registration onto the second page of registration

Tags: joomla, jomsocial

Currently my first page of registration shows these fields:

```
First Name
Last Name
Username
Email
Password
Verify Password
```

After clicking "Next" the First Name and Last Name fields are automatically filled in with what was filled in on the previous page. I would like to display the email from the previous page, but I'm unsure of what "field code" to use. I am also using JoomlaXi's JomSocial Profile Types (JSPT), but I'm not too sure if that even matters in this situation.

On the backend I would go to Components > JomSocial > Custom Profiles > "New Field"

```
Name: Email
Type: Email
Groups: User Contact Info
Field Code: (no idea what to put here to display the email already provided)
Registration: Yes
Visible: Personal
Tooltip: N/A
Read Only: Yes
Published: Yes
Required: Yes
```

Thank you very much, I did try my best to search and look for answer, so I apologize in advanced if this is already covered somewhere else, but after 45mins of looking I decided to try my luck here. Thanks again and any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can achieve it, you can give it a try creating a custom field in:

```
components/com_community/libraries/fields/
```

there you will create "yourfield.php" and in the

```
getFieldData()
```

method you can pull the actual email value;

Otherwise you might edit the

```
components/com_community/templates/your_template/register.profile.php
```

and just hardcode it there.